# Java CMS Options

Tags: java, content-management-system

I wanted to know if there is any open source java cms available in market with which I can make entries to database.

My basic need is:
1. Create Categories(Hierarchical will do)
2. Create SubTypes of categories(Hierarchical will do)
3. Create Products
4. Associate sub types to Categories
5. Associate Products to sub types

All these entries should go to db and from there I can render my jsp's.

Sorry if my question is quite basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms can help. Are you looking to use the CMS exclusively or only use the DB and you have your own JSPs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for [OpenCms](http://www.opencms.org/en/). There is also [eAdmin / OWX opensource project](http://www.eadmin.ch/pages/en/home/) which is Struts2 based, and you get plenty of jsp files to extend and work with.

Comment: Already looking into & Learning it. But can you please tell me how can I handle it. Just need brief. Also How can I make database entries from forms. I just see xml contents.

Comment: Maybe this http://www.opencms.org/en/support/tour/index.html?file=0ea41282-3076-11dc-84e6-b7a33137a728&index=13 will help. OpenCms is fairly large and it usually takes a little time to learn, but this time is well spent...

Comment: Ok, Thanks very much for the help. It would be great if you clear my last doubt. In near future I will be integrating shopping cart with my site. So will OpenCms support my requirement?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact there is a Konakart (http://www.konakart.com/) module you can fit into openCms in no time!

Comment: Yeh, great help. I am relatively newbie in web development. Thanks for all the help. I will evaluate all the things and will update here.

Comment: For many days i wasnt working on it. But want to again start on this RnD. Any Idea is there any caching mechanism available with which i can read data. Like I am adding Products data and i want to read it and keep it in POJO. Or is there any caching mechanism available with opencms which updates data in POJO as update is available?